# Como inserir variáveis do python no execute() do MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python, query

estou com a seguinte situação:

[image: Meu código]

Meu objetivo, é através de uma consulta MySQL no banco de dados,e eu possa retornar um outro valor da mesma coluna.
**No meu caso, é, através do CNPJ, quero que a consulta me retorne a senha do cliente.**

Mas estou tendo o problema que, na *linha 15*, eu não consigo inserir a variável *pesquisar_cnpj*, tentei de todas as formas, mas a única que coisa que me retorna é um parênteses vazio (). Como mostra captura abaixo (Não sei, mas é como se a variável estivesse vazia, não sei se está correto:

[image: Output do terminal]

Por favor me ajudem, preciso muito de uma resposta.

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pelo que eu to vendo você não ta inserindo a variável cnpj dentro da string SELECT do comando cursor.execute. Tenta inserir dessa forma:

```
sql = "SELECT senha FROM bancodedados WHERE cnpj = %s"
cpnj = ("00.000.000/0000-00", )

cursor.execute(sql, cnpj)
valoreslido = cursor.fetchall()
```

Caso você queira um comando mais limpo e nítido pode inserir a variável de forma mais fácil:

```
cpnj = "00.000.000/0000-00"

cursor.execute(f"SELECT senha FROM bancodedados WHERE cnpj = '{cpnj}'")
valoreslido = cursor.fetchall()
```